# How to use the checkboxs in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net form displaying the user details from an Oracle database, using a grid-view. I even managed to get a check-box field in the grid-view using the following template..

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chck"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want the admin to be able to select multiple entries using the check-boxes and perform a certain action on them. I tried using, for the delete operation, the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == true))
                GridView1.Rows.RemoveAt[i];
        }
```

However, this shows an error. Apparently, each check-box on each row must have its own unique index. How do I get to it?
Any sort of help will be appreciated. Thanx :)

Comment: What is the error? And why you are comparing `GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value` as a `boolean`? Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find control inside your gridview row using findControl

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControls("chck");
        if(cb1.Checked)
            GridView1.Rows.RemoveAt[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find control to get checkboxes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
   {

        CheckBox chck = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chck");

       if (chck  != null)
       {
         if (chck.Checked)
         {
            GridView1.Rows.RemoveAt[i];
         }
       }
  }
```

Comment: I've got the adding checkbox to gridview part, thanks. The only problem I'm facing is that, how do I retrieve the primary keys of the checked rows and use them to delete the records?

Comment: You can add an label with value bound to your primary key and get that label value in same manner as you are doing for checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

This is Aspx FIle :

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"  
    CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" DataKeyNames="CategoryID" Font-Size="10"
    Font-Names="Arial" GridLines="Vertical" Width="40%">

            <Columns>            
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server"
                            AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged"
                            Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Approved")) %>'
                            Text='<%# Eval("Approved").ToString().Equals("True") ? " Approved " : " Not Approved " %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>                   
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" />                   
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName"  />
            </Columns>

    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336699" ForeColor="White" Height="20" />

</asp:GridView>
```

This is CS File :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    LoadData();
  }
}

private void LoadData()
{
  string constr = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;uid=waqas;pwd=sql;";
  string query = @"SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName, Approved FROM Categories";

  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, constr);
  DataTable table = new DataTable();
  da.Fill(table);

  GridView1.DataSource = table;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}

public void chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkStatus = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chkStatus.NamingContainer;


    string cid = row.Cells[1].Text;
    bool status = chkStatus.Checked;


    string constr = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;uid=waqas;pwd=sql;";
    string query = "UPDATE Categories SET Approved = @Approved WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);


    com.Parameters.Add("@Approved", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = status;
    com.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cid;


    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    LoadData();
}
```